# AWS Route53 hosted zone creation time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm trying to know when hosted zone was created.

I checked in AWS Console on the hosted zone page, there is no information.
Also aws cli did not help as well:

```
aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id Z1R8UBAEXAMPLE
```

Are there a way to know when AWS Route 53 hosted zone?

Comment: After finding this piece of information is not returned from the r53 api, I'm a bit surprised too. I guess the only way to get this is from CloudTrail IF you have trail enabled before the zone is created.